# Comparing 2 columns in 2 sheets and shows matching but does not show no match

Tags: vba, excel

Here's my code. This compares 2 columns from different sheets (2 sheets) and then reflect the answer in another sheets but it fails to show the data that has no match. I came across an error that says Run Time '91': Object variable r With block variable not set.

Here's the code. Please help.

```
Sub lookup()
Dim TotalRows As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Long

'Copy lookup values from sheet1 to sheet3
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
TotalRows = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
Range("A1:A" & TotalRows).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A1")

'Go to the destination sheet
Sheets("Sheet3").Select

For i = 1 To TotalRows
    'Search for the value on sheet2
    Set rng = Sheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Find(Cells(i, 1).Value)
    'If it is found put its value on the destination sheet
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        Cells(i, 2).Value = rng.Value
    Else
        Cells(i, 4).Value = rng.Value    <------------stops here
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
Cells(i, 4).Value = rng.Value
```

To this:

```
Cells(i, 4).Value = "Not found"
```

Comment: This works sir. But What i want is like this. sheet 1 column a has red,black,blue and orange while sheet 2 column a has red and orange only. Now I want to put black and blue to cells(i, 4) since they have no match. How can I attain this.

Comment: instead of "Not found" maybe put `Cells(i, 1).Value`.  THat is what's being searched for, and so that is what value isn't found.

Comment: It only works and gets the data in sheet1 column A data which has no match. But it doesn not get the data in sheet 2 column A data which has no match.

Comment: You didn't specify that, so I did not do that. It should be easy enough to add another loop to do a reverse comparison, but I will leave that exercise to you, lest you not learn anything :)

Comment: Yes Sir,Thanks for the help anyways.

Comment: You are basically going to need to repeat the entire loop, basically copying everything except the `Dim` statements, and change Sheet1 to Sheet2 and vice versa. Do you understand why?  Then you will need to make some change instead of using `For i = 1 to ...` so that you continue to write in the *next* empty row in your comparison sheet.  Why don't you try that, if you get stuck, ask a new question. :)

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to assign `Nothing` to a cell if no match is found:

```
If Not rng Is Nothing Then
    Cells(i, 2).Value = rng.Value 'rng has a value
Else
    Cells(i, 4).Value = rng.Value 'rng has NO value, ie is Nothing
End If
```

This is not possible and that's why you get the error.